# Best way to rename mount point in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have two drives in my Hyper-V 2012 R2 Core server. C drive is a boot drive and C:\RAID is a mount point to a RAID array. I want to change C:\RAID to be D:

Should I update my configs and storage paths in powershell before I change the mount points or after? What would be the best method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I want to change C:\RAID to be D:

If you just need to rename "RAID" to "D" , it may work .

```
ren c:\RAID D
```

"D:" won't work , because folder name can not contain character ":" .

[Windows Mount Point Folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321(v=ws.11).aspx)

You can use "diskpart" to create a new mount point (d:\test) for volume (7), then remove the old mount point (c:\test) .

```
md d:\test

diskpart

select volume 7

assign mount="d:\test"

remove mount="c:\test"
```